# Random position of images should not overlap other images within a div

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div within an angular component that has an ngFor for images. These images get dynamically placed inside this div by a simple function that runs and returns a random number for the top position and left position.

**The Problem**, many times, the images don't utilize the entire space available and end up overlapping the previous image. I do not want the images getting overlapped by any other images.

**What I tried**. As you'll notice the randomPosition() function checks against an object list of previously used positions. This helped in images being in the same EXACT position, but the overlap still existed. I also tried googling for a library that would easily offer a feature like this to kind of "scatter" the images as well as, some better ways to randomly generate the top and left position but came up empty.

Each image is set to 100px by 100px with a padding of 10px. Code is below.

**project.component.html**

```
<div #imageContainer class="card card-body image-container">
     <img *ngFor="let image of products" class="product-gravatar" [src]="image.src" [style]="image.style"/>
</div>
```

**project.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('imageContainer') imageContainer: ElementRef;

arrangeImages() {
    let used_V = [];
    let used_H = [];
    for (var i = this.products.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

       let containerHeight = this.imageContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
       let containerWidth = this.imageContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth;

       let imageWidth = 100;
       let imageHeight = 100;

       let availableSpace_V = containerHeight - imageHeight;
       let availableSpace_H = containerWidth - imageWidth;

       let random_V = randomPosition(availableSpace_V, used_V);
       let random_H = randomPosition(availableSpace_H, used_H);

       used_V.push(random_V);
       used_H.push(random_H);

       this.products[i]['style'] = 'top:'+random_V+'px; left:'+random_H+'px;';
   }
}

function randomPosition(availableSpace, used) {
  let generatedNumber: number;
  let randomizer = () => generatedNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * availableSpace);
  let check = () => used.find(i => i === generatedNumber);
  randomizer();

  if(check()) {
   randomizer();
  } else {
   return generatedNumber;
  }
}
```

**project.component.css**

```
.image-container {
    max-height: 40vh;
    min-height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container .product-gravatar {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F3715C;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Did you figure it out - I need something similar?